# Boostrap HTML table generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, bootstrap-table

This is my HTML table (I used Bootstrap):

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">From</th>
              <th scope="col">Status</th>
              <th scope="col">Message</th>
              <th scope="col">Accept?</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Pending</td>
              <td>Help me!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Pending</td>
              <td>Help me!</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Now I would like to generate it automatically from javascript in this way:

```
var table=document.getElementById('myTable');

function myFunction() {


    var index = 0;


        var row = table.insertRow(index);


        for(i=0;i<2;i++){
            var cell=row.insertCell(i)
            cell.innerHTML = '<tr><th scope="row">1</th><td>Mark</td><td>Pending</td><td>Help me!</td></tr>'

        }

        index++;
    }
```

For sure, the HTML page and the javascript are linked using  and then at the bottom of the html page I added:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(myFunction())
</script>
```

Comment: If you're going to use insertRow to generate a TR, and insertCell to generate a TD, don't put the whole tr/td markup inside the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append the full html for the row, then don't try to use the insertRow/insertCell "features", rather:

```
var tbody = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");

function myFunction() {
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    tbody.innerHTML += '<tr><th scope="row">1</th><td>Mark</td><td>Pending</td><td>Help me!</td></tr>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, but I guess this is the right way. I'll work on that. Thank you @James